# Getting does not override error even though i did override everything that was abstract

Tags: java, overriding, abstract

So i just made myself one abstract class and two subclasses for my state pattern. But for some bloody reason i cannot run the program because its giving me this error:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - model.cannon.SingleShotState is not abstract and does not override abstract method shoot(model.cannon.Cannon) in model.cannon.CannonState
    at model.cannon.CannonState.(CannonState.java:14)

The problem is, i am overriding the method which it says i do not. Heres my implementation:

```
public abstract class CannonState {
    public abstract Missile[] shoot(Cannon cannon);
}

public class SingleShotState extends CannonState{

    public SingleShotState(){
    }

    @Override
    public Missile[] shoot(Cannon cannon) {
        float x = 1;
        float y = (float) Math.tan(Math.toRadians((double)cannon.getAngle()));

        Random rand = new Random();
        if(rand.nextFloat() < 0.5f){
            cannon.setState(new ShotGunState());
        }

        return new Missile[] {
            new Missile(cannon.getX(),cannon.getY(),1*x*cannon.getForce(),-1*y*cannon.getForce())
        };
    }
}
```

IDE shows me no erros (i am using netbeans 8.2). What could possibly be the problem?

Comment: Are you sure this is the same `Cannon` class? (And same `Missile` class?)

Comment: Check your import statements.  Make sure that the Missile and Cannon you are using are exactly the same.

Comment: "IDE shows me no erros" - that seems very likely if you've got an "Uncompilable source code" error. It sounds like you're not even compiling this code...

Comment: Yes, there are the same classes, both have only one Cannon and Missile implementation in my project. @JonSkeet what do you mean?

Comment: I mean that it's clearly failed to compile successfully, so if you're not seeing any errors in your IDE, you haven't actually compiled it in your IDE recently. I suggest you make a clearly broken change in the code, e.g. add a line saying "this is rubbish" between methods - see whether that shows up as an error. I'd be surprised to see that *that's* an error, but the current code isn't.

Comment: Can you put complete code?

Comment: @Anderiel, I hope you are adding the additional codes for this, meanwhile I just put your code into eclipse and made empty methods to get out of the _redLines_ error, By only looking upto this much, I can suggest you to restart your IDE and run any other simple java code, and then after Check again if error is removed or not.! AllTheBest..!!

Comment: @JonSkeet i am compiling it inside the ide and if i make a broken statement, that does get tagged as an error. As for the complete code, the project is about 20 files. Only other code than what i put there, that has to do something with the error would be the assignment CannonState state = new SingleShotState();

Comment: Your existing code may be 20 files, but you should be able to reduce it to a [mcve] which you can post - while doing so, you're likely to find the problem. Basically, it sounds like your project structure may be a little messed up - the code you've provided compiles fine, and clearly the error starts with the compiler, given that it's "uncompilable source".

Answer (score 0):

The error dissapeared after adding an emty constructor to the abstract class.